# Get the values from Route

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm in developing a dynamic view composer and I need to get the values of routes.

for example, I have these three routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'join', 'as' => 'join-'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'JoinController@index')->name('index');

    Route::group(['prefix' => '{j}/signin', 'as' => 'signin-'], function () {
       Route::get('/', 'SigninController@index')->name('index');

       Route::group(['prefix' => '{f}/forget', 'as' => 'forget-'], function () {
           Route::get('/', 'ForgetController@index')->name('index');
       });

    });
});
```

now I want to catch the `$j` and `$f` values in my view composer.

I can get the name of my routes via `Route::currentRouteName()` but I need to get the values that passed to this routes.

because I need to use `route()` to create a link, for `join-` there is no any problem because we don't need to pass any parameter but in `join-signin-` and `join-signin-forget-` I have Laravel error.

Comment: The route parameters are passed as function parameters to the route handler (e.g. `function ($j) {...}` you can then just pass those as view parameters to any view that would require them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I will write it down might others have this question too.

to get the current route parameters we can use the below method:

```
Route::current()->parameters();
```

or

```
Route::getCurrentRequest()->route()->parameters;
```